# Strange behavior in helper method DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I see a weird thing in `DropDownListFor`. This is a part of My View:

```
1:<dt>
2:  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainModel.DefaultAreaId)
3:</dt>
4:<dd>
5: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainModel.DefaultAreaId, Model.FKs["DefaultAreaId"].Items, new { @class = "Areadd" })
6: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainModel.DefaultAreaId, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
7:</dd>
```

I Check in Debug the Last Line of My Controller: `return View(model);` And the values of `Model.FKs["DefaultAreaId"].Items` is:

```
 0: {Title="t1", value=13, Selected = false},
 1: {Title="t2", value=15, Selected = false},
 2: {Title="t3", value=17, Selected = false},
 3: {Title="t4", value=16, Selected = true}
```

Also I Check it in line 2 of above view and the values is same, But Exactly after line 5 after `DropDownListFor` values Change to:

```
 0: {Title="t1", value=13, Selected = false},
 1: {Title="t2", value=15, Selected = false},
 2: {Title="t3", value=17, Selected = false},
 3: {Title="t4", value=16, Selected = false}
```

I can't understand what happen with `DropDownListFor` and my model values? I also use the same way in same view :

```
11:<dt>
12:  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainModel.DefaultControllerId)
13:</dt>
14:<dd>
15: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainModel.DefaultControllerId, Model.FKs["DefaultControllerId"].Items, new { @class = "Controllerdd" })
16: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainModel.DefaultControllerId, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
17:</dd>
```

And everything is fine, I also change the name of `DefaultAreaId` but nothing change.
So does any one have any explanation for this? what happen here?
if needed I can copy all of my View, Controller and Model.

**Update**

In Controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> Areas = new List<SelectListItem>();
Areas.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "t1", Value = "13", Selected = false });
Areas.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "t2", Value = "15", Selected = false });
Areas.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "t3", Value = "17", Selected = false });
Areas.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "t4", Value = "16", Selected = true });

Model.FKs.Add("DefaultAreaId", new ForeignKey { Title = "area", Items = Areas });
```

`Fks`:

```
public Dictionary<string, ForeignKey> FKs { get; set; }
```

And `ForeignKey` is:

```
public class ForeignKey {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: May you add how do u get the items ??

Comment: @Wahid Bitar I update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **assign default value** to `model.MainModel.DefaultAreaId` in the controller before sending the model to the view.

***Update :***

---

***However here is a better way "as i assume :)"***
I've a helper method to set Selected Item in the list like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SetSelected(this IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object selectedValue)
{
    selectList = selectList ?? new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (selectedValue == null)
        return selectList;
    var vlaue = selectedValue.ToString();
    return selectList.BuildList(m => m.Text, m => m.Value, null, m => String.Equals(m.Value, vlaue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

***Here if you want the BuildList helber and you can use it whenever you want SelectItem list***

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BuildList<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> text, Func<T, string> value = null, string optionalText = null, Func<T, bool> selected = null)
{
    var list = items.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                             Text = text.Invoke(x),
                                             Value = value == null
                                                             ? text.Invoke(x)
                                                             : value.Invoke(x),
                                             Selected = selected != null && selected.Invoke(x)
                                     }).ToList();
    if (optionalText != null)
        list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() {Value = "", Text = optionalText});
    return list;
}
```

in the controller don't do anything but set the value you want to the model:

```
public ActionResult Edit(){
   var model = new YourModel();
   model.CategoryId = 4;
   //.. set the dropdownlist items in the ViewData or in your model in your case
   return View(model);
}
```

and in the view just call DropDownListFor as usual and just call for `SetSelected` helper method:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Categories"]).SetSelected(model.CategoryId))
```

And that would be in your example :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainModel.DefaultAreaId, Model.FKs["DefaultAreaId"].Items.SetSelected(model.MainModel.DefaultAreaId))
```

Just don't forget to set the default value in your Controller.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try your answer, but what happen here? where is the problem with my code?

Comment: As i told you i think your problem because you're not setting `MainModel.DefaultAreaId` value in the controller before sending the model to the view

Comment: BTW I updated my answer to put the BuildList helper method if you want it as well :)

Comment: Thank you, your right, the answer just is: add this to controller: `Model.MainModel.DefaultAreaId = 16;`

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the SelectList are you passing in the selected value there or assigning it via the select list item.

```
var selectList = new SelectList([select list items], "[Key]", "[Value]", [SelectedValue]);
var selectList = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name", 2);
```

Thanks,